# Trying to print out object contents using a class method. Keep getting "error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function"

Tags: c++, class, constructor, output, overloading

**beginner here**, I am working on an assignment for a course and while working on this program, I am experiencing some troubles. I cannot figure out how to print out the contents within an object I have in my main method using a different method from a class I made.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Book {
    private:
        string title;
        int pages;
        double price;
    public:
        Book () {
            title = "";
            pages = 0;
            price = 0.0;
        }
        Book(string t, int p, double pr) {
            title = t;
            pages = p;
            price = pr;
        }
        void setPrice(double);
        void getBookInfo(Book, Book);
};

void Book::setPrice(double pr) {
    price = pr;
}

void Book::getBookInfo(Book b1, Book b2) {
    cout << b1.title << b1.pages << b1.price << endl;
    cout << b2.title << b2.pages << b2.price << endl;
}

int main() {

    Book b1("C++ Programming", 802, 90.55);
    Book b2("Chemistry Tests", 303, 61.23);

    b2.setPrice(77.22);

    b1.getBookInfo;
    b2.getBookInfo;

    return 0;
}
```

I need to print out the contents of *Book b1* and *Book b2* using the *getBookInfo()* method, but every time I think I know what I'm doing, I get "error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function" on *b1.getBookInfo* and *b2.getBookInfo.*

Of course, I will format it on my own so the output isn't all bunched together, but I can't even get it to output anything!

**This is my first time working with class and constructors, so I am really kinda lost right now. Help is appreciated! Thank you!**

Comment: `b1.getBookInfo;` -- This is not the way to call a function with no arguments.  In the C++ book you're using, what syntax does the book show when calling a 0-argument function?

Comment: Please don't use `cout` in a class member function. Please don't EVER `using namespace std;`.

Comment: In addition, you forgot `#include <string>`, plus `getBookInfo` takes two arguments.  So either way, you failed to call `getBookInfo` with two arguments, and if it were meant to take no arguments, the syntax to do that is wrong.

Comment: First, `getBookInfo` shouldn't have any arguments.  Why are you passing two books to the object method?  Aren't you supposed to print the information about the current (`this`) book?  The `Book` object has `title`, `pages`, etc. already, and that is what you should be using, not some other book's information.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Well, really it should have one argument -- the ostream being output to.  Bad habits should be nipped in the bud, even if the textbook teaches those bad habits.

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your help! Also, thanks for the criticism haha. No hard feelings, everyone :) I know how you feel looking at my abomination and my lack of knowledge. It's a mess I know. I am going to clean it up the best I can. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: @krasi We've all been there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from here:

```
b1.getBookInfo;
b2.getBookInfo;
```

you are trying to call methods of a class but didn't use the call operator `()` so you are instead loading the address of the method. To solve this error use the call operator to call the methods:

```
b1.getBookInfo(b1, b2);
b2.getBookInfo(b1, b2);
```

beside that your code has many faults but you indicated you are a beginner so this isn't unusual

Comment: Well, it'll compile at least.